# Parsing date with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have a date of the type

> August 15, 2009

I'm trying to parse it with

> DATE_FORMAT('August 15, 2009', '%M %e, %Y')

But it <del>is not working</del> returns `NULL`.

Oh mighty overflowers, do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I've edited to question to explain the problem.

Comment: Thank you :) You are right your edit makes more sense in a strict way, and we need to be strict when it comes to programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
```

Comment: More specifically, `DATE_FORMAT()` expects a date, that's why it's unsuitable for the task.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't considered that :) Should have looked closer at the manual :)